# how to run multiple command in a single line in ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to a run two  ansible command in a single line. While am running the command its taking only the second command .

```
ansible -i list  cdlk -a "touch /tmp/a" -a "touch /tmp/b" --private-key=/tmp/id_rsa
```

I have create a file called list and after running this command only /tmp/b file is getting created .How I can run multiple commands in single line?

Comment: What's wrong with `-a "touch /tmp/a; touch /tmp/b"`?

Comment: its executing only second command  that is "touch /tmp/b"  ./tmp/a is not getting created.

Comment: Even with the change suggested above?

Comment: Yes. Its worked .Thank you

Answer (score 2):

By default ansible CLI uses command module, which does not feed its arguments trough shell.change your parameter according to requirement.An example is shared below

You want to use shell module instead:

```
ansible host -m shell -a 'echo hello && echo world'
```